# C# Database adding to a table

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010

I am using a .mdf database in Visual Studio 2010. When I add information to my table I get error. I don't get any problem when I add the first four rows. But when I add the fifth row I get error.

Here is the error:

> SqlException was unhandled

What can the problem be?

```
        dataAccess.AddQuestion("Category1", "Question1?", "1");
        dataAccess.AddQuestion("Category2", "Question2?", "2");
        dataAccess.AddQuestion("Category3", "Question3?", "3");
        dataAccess.AddQuestion("Category4", "Question4?", "4");
        dataAccess.AddQuestion("Category5", "Question5?", "5");
```

I get the error when I add the question number five.

Here is the method for how I add the information to the table in the database.

```
    public void AddQuestion(string title, string question, string answer)
    {

        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO QuestionTable VALUES(@Title, @Question, @Answer)", sqlConnection);

        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Title", title));
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Question", question));
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Answer", answer));
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Knowing what error you are getting would be quite helpful.

Comment: You should dispose your `sqlCommand` object.

Comment: have u caught an exception with your? `catch (Exception ex)`

Comment: And what is the inner exception?

Comment: This it the error I get: SqlException was unhandled.
Yes I caught the exception with catch (Exception ex)

Comment: could you please add the StackTrace?

Comment: Wrap your connection and command in using statements. Also what's the point of catching and then just re-throwing an exception am I missing something?

Comment: Don't catch an exception unless you intend to do something with it.

Comment: By the way it's better to open connection right before sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: I have used the using statement also but I get the same error.

Comment: Don't throw the exception.comment that line for a while add a Response.Write(ex.ToString()); and post the stack trace that is displayed. That would help us to help you out

Comment: What namespace should I use for the Response.Write(ex.ToString()); ?

Comment: I have found the problem! In the database I was using nvarchar(50), but I hade one string which was 52 characters. I got the error because of that.

Comment: Well, you were the only one who could possibly know that. Your question was misleading, to start with (check the method call parameters, they have all the same length).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a reason not to use method scoped variables for the SQL objects? Try to use this:

```
public void AddQuestion(string title, string question, string answer)
{

    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO QuestionTable VALUES(@Title, @Question, @Answer)", sqlConnection))
    {
        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Title", title));
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Question", question));
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Answer", answer));
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex); 
            throw; 
        }
    }
}
```

If you consider moving to SQL Server 2008 or newer, you might also look into [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx).

Comment: @SonerGönül, read this article, [What are the limitations of MS Access?](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-are-the-limitations-of-ms-access.html): _Microsoft doesn't even publish hard numbers; they just use off-hand references such as "ten or fewer" and never truly define what they mean by "high-concurrency."_

Comment: @SonerGönül I think this is relevant because including the using statements might have prevented the problem (i.e not disposing the command and connection objects) hence solve his problem.

Comment: You're hiding your exception stack trace by the way you are rethrowing. change the catch block to `catch(Exception ex) { System.Diagnotstics.Debug.WriteLine(ex); throw; }`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use multiple insert statement to insert multiple rows at once as their is always a limit on the no of connection to database per app pool so either you must not close the connection or use multiple insert at once

Answer (score 0):

try the following code maybe you need to [lock()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

```
    private static readonly object Locker = new object();
    public void AddQuestion(string title, string question, string answer)
    {

        lock (Locker)
        {
            try
            {
                sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("");

                sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO QuestionTable VALUES(@Title, @Question, @Answer)", sqlConnection);

                sqlConnection.Open();
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Title", title));
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Question", question));
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Answer", answer));
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("That is the Error:" ex.ToString()); // post this Text if it doesn't work
                throw (ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem (error)! In the database I was using nvarchar(50), but I hade one string which was 52 characters. I got the error because of that.